# Can't launch multiple idempeire swing client

Tags: java, hazelcast, idempiere

I'm new to idempiere. Running first idempiere swing client 4.1 (daily version) just fine. But i can't run another instance.

Checking with eclipsec.exe had the following logs

```
D:\idempiere-client\adempiere.win32.win32.x86_64\adempiere-client>eclipsec.exe
Mar 29, 2021 8:59:51 AM org.adempiere.client.Application start
INFO: Starting client
Mar 29, 2021 8:59:51 AM org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpClientHelper start
INFO: Starting the internal HTTP client
Mar 29, 2021 8:59:51 AM org.compiere.Adempiere startup
INFO: iDempiere(r) Release 4.1_2016-10-31 -Smart Suite ERP, CRM and SCM- (c) 1999-2016 iDempiere(r); Implementation: iDempiere - Supported by iDempiere community
Mar 29, 2021 8:59:51 AM org.compiere.util.Ini loadProperties
INFO: C:\Users\Sapta\idempiere.properties #36
[INFO] MLog clients using com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog logging.
[INFO] Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
Loading...
[INFO] Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 2, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfter
AcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> i
DempiereDS, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.postgresql.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynch
ronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hgeby9agybox3k1ncdz4c|21337f7b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 1200, initialPoolSize -> 1, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.190:5432/idempi
ere?encoding=UNICODE, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1200, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 1200, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize
-> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> SELECT Version FROM AD_System, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads
-> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
*** 2021-03-29 08:59:52.064 idempiere Log (CLogConsole) ***
08:59:52.064 DefaultAddressPicker: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.5.3] Picked Address[192.168.1.111]:5703, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5703], bind any local is true [24]
08:59:52.076-----------> ServiceLoader: Service loader could not load 'META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension' It may be empty or does not exist. [24]
08:59:52.086-----------> ServiceLoader: Service loader could not load 'META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.PortableHook' It may be empty or does not exist. [24]
08:59:52.086-----------> ServiceLoader: Service loader could not load 'META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.DataSerializerHook' It may be empty or does not exist. [24]
08:59:52.096-----------> ServiceLoader: Service loader could not load 'META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.SerializerHook' It may be empty or does not exist. [24]
08:59:52.116 OperationService: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Backpressure is disabled [24]
08:59:52.116 ClassicOperationExecutor: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Starting with 6 generic operation threads and 12 partition operation threads. [24]
08:59:52.266 system: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Hazelcast 3.5.3 (20151011 - 64c663a) starting at Address[192.168.1.111]:5703 [24]
08:59:52.266 system: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved. [24]
08:59:52.657 Node: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Creating MulticastJoiner [24]
08:59:52.657 LifecycleService: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Address[192.168.1.111]:5703 is STARTING [24]
08:59:52.816 MulticastJoiner: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Trying to join to discovered node: Address[192.168.1.111]:5701 [24]
08:59:52.816 SocketConnector: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Connecting to /192.168.1.111:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true [76]
08:59:52.816 TcpIpConnectionManager: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Established socket connection between /192.168.1.111:51206 [76]
08:59:52.826 TcpIpConnection: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Connection [Address[192.168.1.111]:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!] [67]
08:59:52.826-----------> ReadHandler: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[192.168.1.111]:5701, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed! [67]
08:59:53.918 MulticastJoiner: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Trying to join to discovered node: Address[192.168.1.111]:5701 [24]
08:59:53.918 SocketConnector: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Connecting to /192.168.1.111:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true [78]
08:59:53.918 TcpIpConnectionManager: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Established socket connection between /192.168.1.111:51208 [78]
08:59:53.918 TcpIpConnection: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Connection [Address[192.168.1.111]:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!] [69]
08:59:53.918-----------> ReadHandler: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-1 Closing socket to endpoint Address[192.168.1.111]:5701, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed! [69]
08:59:55.019 MulticastJoiner: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Trying to join to discovered node: Address[192.168.1.111]:5701 [24]
08:59:55.019 SocketConnector: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Connecting to /192.168.1.111:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true [78]
08:59:55.019 TcpIpConnectionManager: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Established socket connection between /192.168.1.111:51210 [78]
08:59:55.019 TcpIpConnection: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] Connection [Address[192.168.1.111]:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!] [71]
08:59:55.019-----------> ReadHandler: [192.168.1.111]:5703 [dev] [3.5.3] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2 Closing socket to endpoint Address[192.168.1.111]:5701, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed! [71]
```

Anyone can help me ?
Machine :

- Win 10 x64
- Java 1.8.0_251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very old version (2016), it's recommended to stay up to date with versions to avoid security issues.

iDempiere is running nowadays in 8.2 version and java 11

Swing client still works in a limited fashion, but its usage is strongly discouraged because of security and obsolescence.

Comment: Thank you Carlos, after about 2 years implemented, web version somewhat more better than desktop version, especially on how to maintain. Currently putting aside print quality on dot matrix printers,